# Passing arguments in unix in command line

Tags: linux, unix, arguments, command-line-arguments

How can I pass arguments to a command in unix? For example, if I have to open a file:

```
R> vi john/pic/mars/NASA/rover.txt
```

In the above `vi` command, I want to replace "mars" with a variable, and pass the variable value in the same line, as in:

```
R> vi john/pic/$variable/NASA/rover.txt | $varaiable=pluto
```

Of course this doesn't work. But I hope my question is clear. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: @n.m. I would have thought so, too, but the variable actually only gets defined in the launched process itself, not the current command-line (in Bash 4.2.45(1); probably a feature). Have you actually tried it (without the typo?).

Comment: Sorry about the typo. Yes, I have tried without typo also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply move the variable definition to the beginning of the command line, as in:

```
variable=pluto; vi john/pic/$variable/NASA/rover.txt
```

or even:

```
variable=pluto && vi john/pic/$variable/NASA/rover.txt
```

*OBS*:

1. notice you can't use `$` while defining variables, only while using their values;
2. piping your `vi` command to a variable assignment does not make much sense, although you could achieve some *clearer parameterization* from:

   ```
   function opener() {
       vi john/pic/$1/NASA/rover.txt
   }
   $ opener "pluto"
   ```